# how to click on text area to send long text using ruby with selenium web driver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, textarea, rubymine

I tried xpath and id
 getting `until': timed out after 10 seconds (no such element (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError)
I am using rubymine editor.

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
wait.until { @driver.find_element(:xpath => "//*[@id='j_id0:pb:j_id35']") }
@driver.find_element(:xpath => "//*[@id='j_id0:pb:j_id35']").send_keys "test send sms"
```

Text area element is placed on bottom of the page.Do I need to scroll down the page and click and sendkeys in the text area.
in the below code I am trying to find nearest element to the text box and do scroll down later click on text area and sendkeys.But even it's not working..

```
 #wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
#wait.until { @driver.find_element(:name => "j_id0:pb:j_id33") }
#scroll = @driver.find_element(:name => "j_id0:pb:j_id33")
#scroll.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

Please help on this..
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have idea on rudy but can help you logically..

1) first scroll the page from your code to the text area.

2) select the text area by id, xpath or etc. driver.findelement(by.id(...)).sendkey(..........);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Shukla!@sourabh shukla
Mine inside has frame so I need to switch to frame that is why I am not able ciclk that element!!
   @driver.switch_to.frame("06618000000Crrp"#this is id);
Then my element found and entered text!!